# Usando múltiplos group by em uma query

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo 3 Tabelas: Produtos, Pedidos e Item de Pedido.

```
Table: Produtos

id_produto    foto_produto    categoria    sub_categoria
---------------------------------------------------------
0081          15487.jpg       4            32
0491          18987.jpg       3            67
0141          11087.jpg       8            82

Table Pedidos
--------------------------
id_pedidos    data_pedido    
36987         15/11/2015
77897         12/11/2015
59870         11/11/2015

Table: Iten Pedido

id_item_produto   id_pedido
---------------------------
0081              33687
0491              33687
0141              77897
0081              59870
```

Preciso criar uma query que me retorne todas as sub_categoria de uma categoria específica, porém com a foto do produto mais vendido na mesma em um periodo de 15 dias. Eu estou usando a seguinte query:

```
SELECT cod_pedido, inten.id_produto, count(id_produto) AS total, prod.cod_subcategoria1 FROM tb_pedidos_otimin as pedidos
left join tb_itens_pedidos_otimin as inten ON inten.id_pedido = pedidos.cod_pedido
left join tb_produtos_otimin as prod on inten.id_produto = prod.cod_produto
WHERE prod.cod_categoria1 = 38 AND data_pagamento BETWEEN '2015-11-15 00:00:00' and '2015-12-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY id_produto
```

Porém não estou conseguindo ordenar por dois Group By.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aconselho que você normalize seu banco de dados. Um produto pertence a 1 ou n categorias. Uma categoria pertence a 1 ou n subcategorias. Construindo seu banco de dados com essa estrutura, ficaria muito mais simples na hora de fazer sua query.

Acrescentando as tabelas:

```
Table: Produtos

id_produto    foto_produto    id_categoria    
-------------------------------------------
0081          15487.jpg       4            
0491          18987.jpg       3            
0141          11087.jpg       8           

Table Pedidos
--------------------------
id_pedidos    data_pedido    
36987         15/11/2015
77897         12/11/2015
59870         11/11/2015

Table: Iten Pedido

id_item_produto   id_pedido
---------------------------
0081              33687
0491              33687
0141              77897
0081              59870

categoria
-----------
id_categoria    descricao
4               vestuario
3               eletronicos

subCategoria
------------
id_subCategoria      id_categoria   descricao
32                   1              camiseta
67                   1              bermuda
23                   2              notebooks
```

Tendo essa estrutura no banco, o select ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(Iten_Pedido.id_item_produto), produto.foto_produto,
categoria.descricao, subCategoria.descricao, pedido.data_pedido
FROM pedido
INNER JOIN iten_Pedido
ON iten_pedido.id_pedido = pedido.id_pedido
INNER JOIN produtos
ON iten_pedido.id_item_produto = produtos.id_produto
INNER JOIN categorias 
ON produtos.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria
INNER JOIN subcategorias
ON categoris.id_categoria = subcategorias.id_categoria
WHERE  pedido.data_pedido BETWEEN '2015-11-15     00:00:00' and '2015-12-    01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY item_pedido.id_produto, produto.foto_produto,
categoria.descricao, subCategoria.descricao, pedido.data_pedido 
ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1
```

O comando order by DESC ordena os registro do maior para o menos, e o comando limit 1 exibe apenas o primeiro registro (o item com mais pedidos). Aconselho fazer essa query separada. Uma consulta para listar s subcategorias, e outra para o produto mais vendido. Porém, a ideia pra fazer isso numa só consulta está ai. Estou no trabalho então não tive como testar o código, espero ter ajudado! 
OBS: Muitas vezes a cláusula group by precisa ter TODOS OS campos do teu select.